# how to set log retention days for Cloudfront function in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have an example Cloudfront function:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_function" "cool_function" {

  name    = "cool-function"
  runtime = "cloudfront-js-1.0"
  comment = "The cool function"
  publish = true
  code    = <<EOT
function handler(event) {
    var headers = event.request.headers;
    if (
        typeof headers.coolheader === "undefined" ||
        headers.coolheader.value !== "That_is_cool_bro"
    ) {
        console.log("That is not cool bro!")
    }
    return event.request;
}
EOT
}
```

When I create this function, Cloudwatch `/aws/cloudfront/function/cool-function` log group [will be created automatically](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitoring-functions.html)

But log group retention policy is `Never Expire`

And I can't see any [parameters in terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_function) that allow to set retention days

So the question is:

is it possible to automatically import [`aws_cloudwatch_log_group`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_log_group) every time when Cloudfront function creating and change `retention_in_days` for this resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few AWS services create their log groups implicitly on first use. To prevent that you need to explicitly create the group before the service has a chance to do it.

For that you need to define the `aws_cloudwatch_log_group` with the given name yourself, specify the correct retention and then create an explicit `depends_on` relation between the function and the log group to ensure the log group is created first. For migration purposes you now would need to import already created log groups into your terraform state.

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_function" "cool_function" {
    name    = "cool-function"
    ...
    depends_on = [
        aws_cloudwatch_log_group.logs
    ]
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "logs" {
    name              = "/aws/cloudfront/function/cool-function"
    retention_in_days = 123
    ...
}
```

Comment: hmm... create log group preventually? I didn't think about it, thanks for idea. I will check it

Comment: @rzlvmp it is the only reasonable way to set retention, kms encryption and to also delete the log group after you e.g. no longer need the function and remove it from terraform.

Comment: I re-created log group with terraform and all working properly. Retention is set and new logs appeared in log group. Looks like only log group name is important (should be same as function name) and it may be created at any time manually (or as terraform resource)